# How to add a Site Feed(Newsfeed) OOTB web part to one of the tab in a JQuery tabbed UI?

Tags: jquery, visual-web-part, html, jquery-ui, sitefeed

How do I show a Newsfeed webpart in one of the tab in a Custom Tabbed Sandbox Visual Webpart?

I've an html UI using JQuery UI tab. Some of the tabs contain static html, I want to add a new tab say "Newsfeed", and this tab show the OOTB Newsfeed WebPart? 
I'm deploying this HTML/CSS/JS using sandbox Visual Web Part, so all the markeup is in the .ascx file.
I tried to export the OOTB Sitefeed markup and put it in a WebPartZone container and inserted in the tabs html markup as below, does not work -

```
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">                 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Newsfeed Comments" ID="NewsfeedComments" FrameType="TitleBarOnly">
            <ZoneTemplate> 
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
                                  <Title>Site Feed</Title>
                                  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
                                  <Description>Site Feed contains microblogging conversations on a group site.</Description>
                                  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
                                  <ZoneID>Header</ZoneID>
                                  <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
                                  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
                                  <Height />
                                  <Width />
                                  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
                                  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
                                  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
                                  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
                                  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
                                  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
                                  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
                                  <DetailLink />
                                  <HelpLink />
                                  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
                                  <Dir>Default</Dir>
                                  <PartImageSmall />
                                  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
                                  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/wp_pers.gif</PartImageLarge>
                                  <IsIncludedFilter />
                                  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                                  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteFeedWebPart</TypeName>
                                </WebPart>
            </ZoneTemplate>
        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
        </div>
                 </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```